# How can I randomly perturb the position of a grid of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

I have a grid of nodes generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    small-node/.style={
        shape=circle,
        fill=white,
        draw,
        minimum size=+4mm}
}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,4}
        \node [small-node] (n-\i\j) at (\i,\j) {};
\foreach \i in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \j [count=\jj] in {0,...,3}
        \draw (n-\i\j) -- (n-\i\jj) (n-\j\i) -- (n-\jj\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way that as each node is created, I can generate two random numbers in the range (-0.5,0.5) and add those two the x and y coordinates of the node so that they are no longer in a rectilinear grid pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `rnd` or `rand` pgf functions. `rnd` generates a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1 with a uniform distribution, and `rand` does the same between -1 and 1.

Simply change the `node` declaration line with the following:

```
\node [small-node] (n-\i\j) at (\i + 0.5*rand,\j + 0.5*rand) {};
```

[image: Rendering]